# powerpc 32bit gcc compilation causing assembler errors due to GOT overflow

Tags: gcc, elf, powerpc

Context:

I have a Large C file generated by SWIG for python bindings 13MB in size.
When its compiled with powerpc 32bit gcc with -fPIC I get the following error.

> {standard input}:1805519: Error: operand out of range
>   (0x000000000000aab8 is not between 0xffffffffffff8000 and
>   0x0000000000007fff)

As per Internet search in multiple sites this seems to be due to ELF GOT overflow and assembler is unable to fit in 16K entries of 64K GOT.

Question:
As per Powerpc 32bit gcc manual -fPIC means a GOT per function than ELF.
So I want to know the offending function which needs greater than 16K GOT entries due to which compilation fails. Please let me know how to find it out, any gcc options etc.

Comment: Try using `-save-temps` option and removing any `-pipe` option. The error message will contain the name of the generated assembly file. Open it with an editor and find out what function line 1805519 is in.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Probably looks like SWIG_init() trying to install all constants is probably creating the issue.